# 2 AngularJS controllers

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to implement AngularJS UI Bootstrap Typeahead into my small search application.

I want to have a page where users can simply type in there search queries and then be directed to a search results page.

Trying to understand how to implement that with angular routes and controllers

So far I have this as my code:

```
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when("/", {templateUrl: "autocomplete/autocomplete.html", controller: "TypeaheadCtrl"}).
    when("search/:searchTerms", {templateUrl: "search/search.html", controller: "searchCtrl"}).
```

where autocomplete.html is just a page with a search box for user queries and search.html is a page with a search box and for displaying search results list.

How do I have the TypeaheadCtrl on both pages as well as a resultsCtrl on the search results page. A bit confused as to how to do this. Building this project as a way to learn AngularJS.

Comment: Look into directives (or classes in Angular2). You wouldn't need the search.html page at all. You'd have a <search></search> html tag on autocomplete.html that was tied to the input via the TypeaheadCtrl and the directive, through something like $scope.searchInput.

Comment: @AaronGates I kind of want the search.html page, but the directive idea sounds great for the page with just a search box. Could point me to a link with an example?

Comment: Sure. Here: http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/